# How to store objects in a Json file

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to store accounts in a json file. 
Something like : accounts{[user: user1, email: email1], [user: user2. email: email2]}

Javascript file

```
Accounts = {
                Nickname: form.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value,
                Email: form.getElementsByTagName('input')[3].value
            };
    var json = JSON.stringify(Accounts);
    fs.appendFile('Accounts.json', json, function(err){});
```

When I add a second user this code make a new object and it looks like.

Json file

```
{"NickName": "user1", "Email": "Email1"}{"NickName": "user2", "Email": "Email2"}
```

Then, when I try to read the file and parse it I receive an unexpected error {

I think the Json file should look like

`{
  {"Name":"value"}, 
  {"Name2":"value2"} 
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix the issue.
Here the solution with a mix of Michael Brune's solution.

```
// Read accounts.json
    const Accounts = fs.readFileSync('Accounts.json', 'utf-8');

    // Check if json file is empty
    if(Accounts.length !== 0){
        var ParsedAccounts = JSON.parse(Accounts);
    }
    else{
        ParsedAccounts = [];
    }


    ParsedAccounts.push(Account);

    const NewData = JSON.stringify(ParsedAccounts, null, 4);

    // Write new data to accounts.json
    fs.writeFileSync('Accounts.json', NewData);
```

Basically, I push the new data in ParsedAccounts then I write it in the json file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another way, but if your file is pretty small, then try like this:

**Accounts.json:**

```
{
    "other": "other data"
}
```

**index.js**
    const fileData = fs.readFileSync('Accounts.json');

```
let parsedFileData 
try {
  parsedFileData = JSON.parse(fileData);
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof SyntaxError) {
    // Create empty object to append to since parse was not a success
    parsedFileData = {};
    // Create backup of old, possible corrupt file
    fs.writeFileSync('Accounts.backup.json', fileData);
  }
}

const newFileData = JSON.stringify({
  ...parsedFileData,
  ...newDataToAppend,
}, null, 4);

fs.writeFileSync('Accounts.json', newFileData);
```

- First you can parse the file.
- Assign new and old data to a object.
- Then convert that to srting JSON.Stringify

  - The null and 4 are to write a nice pretty file
- Then write it to the file directly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210081/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-bruce-how-to-store-objects-in-a-json-file).